# Calling my function inside JavaScript Alertbox doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, alert

I am a beginner in JavaScript and JQuery. I was just trying to do a program for fun that works just like a prompt box in JavaScript. I created the function and it does work but the problem is when I include it inside an `alert()`, it doesn't wait till my function completes it's execution.

Here is my code:

```
function getString(labeltxt){
    $("body").append("<div class='pageTakeout'><div id='alertzone'><p id='alertzonetext'></p><input type='button' id='alertzoneclicker' value='OK' onclick='returnString()' /></div></div>");
    $("#alertzonetext").text(labeltxt);
    $("#alertzonetext").append("<br><br><input type='text' id='getstring_temptext' name='getstring_temptext' />");
    $(".pageTakeout").css({'display':'block'});
    $("#getstring_temptext").focus();

    getTextVal(function(result){
        return returnString(result);
        });

}

function getTextVal(callback){
        $("#getstring_temptext").keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode==13){
                result=$("#getstring_temptext").val();
                callback(result);
            }
        });    
}

function returnString(result){
    $("#alertzonetext").text('');
    $(".pageTakeout").fadeOut(200,function(){
        $(".pageTakeout").remove();
    });
    var test = result;
    return test;

}

alert(getString('Enter some text'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prompt` and `alert` cannot be replicated due to their synchronous nature.

You'd have to add a callback instead of returning the value (async), the same way you do it for `getTextVal` like this:

```
function getString(labeltxt, callback){
    ...
    getTextVal(function(result){
        callback(returnString(result));
    });
}
```

The final call would have to be:

```
getString('Enter some text', function(string){
   alert(string);
});
```

Cheers